# Not able to perform case insensitive sorting with Solr SortableTextField

Tags: solr

I am facing a problem with sorting on a field with type as mentioned below

```
<fieldType name="string_ci" class="solr.SortableTextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

The field may contain numerical as well as alphabetical values. My Solr version is 7.5.0.

If I sort by "fieldName desc", this field sorts lowercase values first, followed by Uppercase and then the digits.

I want to be able to sort values irrespective of the case and also I don't want to change the class of the field (SortableTextField) as this type will also be used to perform a case-insensitive search on this very field which is working fine.

I supposed, LowerCaseFilterFactory was enough for this scenario. Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: try analysing the same on solr admin page...

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that

> SortableTextField is a specialized form of TextField that supports
>   Sorting and ValueSource functions, using docValues built from the
>   first maxCharsForDocValues characters of the original (pre-analyzed)
>   String values of this field.

which means, that even though you specified analyzer chain it's still would sort original (pre-analyzed) values, which could have upper/lower case. So, if you really want to sort on analyzed values (which is not always the case) you need to use **solr.TextField**. According to your requirements - you would still be able to perform case-insensitive searches using this field, it's just the sorting would work differently.

Comment: yes and that implies I will have to go with copyField for sorting. Thanks!

Comment: @riteshKumar if it helps you, please accept the answer and upvote it

Comment: @Mysterion good answer, nice bit of info, that "pre-analyzed" part. Unfortunately switching to solr.TextField is not option for me, since in my case the field to sort by is multivalued. Do you have any suggestions how to implement a case insensitive sorting on a multivalued field?